# Unit testing HttpResponseMessage with Autofac and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, autofac

I'm going round in circles. So my WebApi returns the output it needs to the browser when i am running in debug. Firefox and IE display the List i need. However when i am trying to unit test the response using Mock and Autofac the `HttpResponseMessage` I am getting back has no Contents. I get the feeling it is returning on a different context or something like that. I am not totally sure, hence asking the question. I have stringed the below unit test together via googling and the Autofac documentation.

WebApiMethod (contained within `InScrapController`, `_WebScrapSprocService` is injected by Autofac in the constructor)

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFormItemsByFormNumber(int FormNumber)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        //response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _WebScrapSprocService.GetFormItemsByFormNumber(FormNumber),new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_WebScrapSprocService.GetFormItemsByFormNumber(FormNumber)),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new StringContent(e.Message), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
    //Checking if bob knows anything about this...
    string bob = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return response;
}
```

Unit Test

```
public void GetFormItemsByFormNumber()
{
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
    {

        var Service = mock.Mock<IWebScrapSprocService>().Setup(x => x.GetFormItemsByFormNumber(3392));
        var service = mock.Create<InScrapController>();
        service.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        service.Request.SetConfiguration(new HttpConfiguration());
        var HttpResponse = service.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Service, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = service.GetFormItemsByFormNumber(3392);
        mock.Mock<IWebScrapSprocService>().Verify(x => x.GetFormItemsByFormNumber(3392));
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpResponse, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those responses are not going to be the same. Also that method under test should be refactored. You are also not getting back any content because you have not setup the service to return anything.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetFormItemsByFormNumber(int FormNumber) {
    IHttpActionResult response;
    try {
        var result = _WebScrapSprocService.GetFormItemsByFormNumber(FormNumber);
        response = Ok(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response = InternalServerError(e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Next update the test

```
public void GetFormItemsByFormNumber() {
    using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose()) {
        // Arrange.
        var formNumber = 3392;
        var items = new List<FormItemsByFormNumber> {
            new FormItemsByFormNumber { 
                //Populate as needed 
            },
            new FormItemsByFormNumber { 
                //Populate as needed 
            },
            //...etc
        };
        var serviceMock = mock.Mock<IWebScrapSprocService>();
        serviceMock.Setup(x => x.GetFormItemsByFormNumber(formNumber)) // Calling this...
            .Returns(items) // should return some value...
            .Verifiable();  // and I want to verify that it was called.
        var sut = mock.Create<InScrapController>();

        // Act.   
        var response = sut.GetFormItemsByFormNumber(formNumber) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<FormItemsByFormNumber>>();

        // Assert.
        serviceMock.Verify(); //verify setups were exercised as expected.
        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: any reason for simply removing `string bob = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` the problem I am having stems form that ReadAsStringAsync simply not being mockable

Comment: I ended up not mocking the response content and just setting up the response